# Find values in a Map using SpEL

Tags: spring, spring-el

We have a Map containing configurations as follows.

```
Class Config {
     Map<String, Boolean> enabled = new LinkedHashMap<String, Boolean> ();
```

The config POJO object is populated from the Spring Cloud Config Server.

The Key value is arrived based on what functionality the user is accessing now.It will have key-values like {'default': true,'login':false,'dashboard':true}
    }

In my Servlet Filter, I want to take the value for a given key (based on user accessing functionality), if key not present, I want to take the 'default' value.

I can write a ternary operator by using map.get to achieve this but, can i do the same using SpEL (Spring Expression Language) ?

```
boolean isEnabled = configuration.getEnabled().get(api) == null ? configuration.getEnabled().get("default") : configuration.getEnabled().get(api);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking but...

`"['foo']?:['default']"`

...if the map contains key `foo`, its value is returned, otherwise the value for `default`.

(This assumes the map is the `#root` object for the evaluation).

See the [Elvis Operator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-operator-elvis).

Comment: The "Collection Selection" in "Elvis Operator" seems to be suitable. Let me try that. Thank you. Will update the question and answer once it works out.

Comment: I thought cannot parse map directly, must should as a property of a bean.